# Axios cors-error "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: reactjs, axios

I would like to get some xml-data from a web-address. Unfortunately I always get an erorr...

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxxx' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Does anybody now how to fix it? Do I have to call it server-side? If yes, how would I do it?

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of variations of your question on Stackoverflow, did you try searching first? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)